Cesaro $(C,\alpha)$ summable implies Abel summable.
I've found quite a few questions regarding the statement "Cesaro $(C,1)$ summability implies Abel summability", e.g. this question, but haven't been able to find a proof for higher Cesaro sums.
My professor says it is true that Cesaro $(C,\alpha)$ summability implies Abel summability for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. How can we prove this fact?

Just to clarify, is the $(C,\alpha)$-summability in your context the same as in this Wikipedia article?

@SangchulLee yes. So $(C,1)$ implies $(C,2)$ implies $(C,3)$ ... and so on.

I will use the definition described in the Wikipedia article. Let $A_n^{(\alpha)}$ be defined via the following implicit relation
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n^{(\alpha)} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{\alpha+1}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n. $$
Note that $A^{(-1)}_n = a_n$ and $A_n^{(\alpha+1)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} A^{(\alpha)}_k$. Also, let $E^{(\alpha)}_n$ be $A^{(\alpha)}_n$ for the sequence $(1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, that is,
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n^{(\alpha)} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{\alpha+1}}. $$
Then the $(C,\alpha)$-sum of $(a_n)$ is defined as
$$ (C,\alpha)\text{-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n := \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A^{(\alpha)}_n}{E^{(\alpha)}_n} $$
if the right-hand side exists. Under this definition, we prove:

Theorem. Let $\alpha > -1$, and assume that $(a_n)$ is $(C,\alpha)$-summable. Then $(a_n)$ is Abel summable and the value of the two sums coincide.

To this end, the following lemma turns out to be useful:

Lemma. Assume $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are two sequences of real numbers such that the followings hold:

$a_n / b_n \to L \in [-\infty, \infty]$ as $n \to \infty$.
$b_n > 0$ for all $n$.
The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ is $1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n = \infty$.

Then we have
$$ \lim_{x \uparrow 1} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n} = L. $$

Proof of Lemma. Suppose $L > -\infty$, and pick an arbitrary $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha < L$. Then there exists $N$ such that $\alpha < \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ for all $n \geq N$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n}
&= \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n - \alpha b_n) x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n} + \alpha \\
&\geq \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N} (a_n - \alpha b_n) x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n} + \alpha.
\end{align*}
Letting $\liminf$ as $x \uparrow 1$, this implies
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{x \uparrow 1} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n}
&\geq \alpha.
\end{align*}
Since this holds true for any $\alpha < L$, letting $\alpha \uparrow L$ tells that the limsup is in fact $\geq L$. Also, by a similar argument, or by applying the above argument to $-a_n/b_n$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{x \uparrow 1} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n}
&\leq L
\end{align*}
whenever $L < +\infty$. Combining these two observation, we conclude the desired claim for any $L \in [-\infty, \infty]$. $\square$
Now we return to the proof of the main theorem. However, it follows almost immediately from the above lemma together with the observation that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n^{(\alpha)} x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n^{(\alpha)} x^n}. $$
